# Nullable object must have a value datetime using c# error

Tags: c#, datetime

I am facing one problem in c# datetime i have trying more than time. it's not 
giving a problem solution. so give me one solution.

```
var accommodationcategoryList = EmployeeAttendanceCacheMaster.GetAllEmployeeAttendance();
DataSourceResult result = accommodationcategoryList.ToDataSourceResult(request);

foreach(var item in accommodationcategoryList)
{
    item.User = UserCacheMaster.GetUserById(item.employeeid);
    item.loginTime = item.login.Value.ToShortDateString();
    item.logoutTime = (item.logout.Value.ToShortDateString() != null) ? item.logout.Value.ToShortDateString() : "-";
}
```

My problem is not showing the logouttime it showing error looks like

> nullable object must have a value

Comment: Surely you meant to use item.logout.HasValue instead

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to check if a conversion against the null object is null rather than checking the nullable object itself.  You need to change this line:

```
item.logoutTime = (item.logout.Value.ToShortDateString() != null) ? item.logout.Value.ToShortDateString() : "-";
```

to

```
item.logoutTime = item.logout.HasValue ? item.logout.Value.ToShortDateString() : "-";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(item.logout.HasValue) {
    item.logoutTime = item.logout.Value;
}
```